# Dog keeps eating my cats medicated food

Tags: dogs, safety, sleep

I have a new puppy and I am trying to train him not to eat the cat food. The cat has worms, so I take some fancy feast and put some liquid wormer in it. Because the cat is still spooked by the dog, I have noticed he wont eat all of his food in one sitting. My dog is waking up in the middle of the night and eating the cat's medicated food.

**Will this hurt him?** and are there any other ways besides putting him in his kennel to get him to stop? I don't want the kennel to be punishment, and he is a barker when I put him in the kennel making it hard to sleep. What do I do?

Comment: Dogs love cat food... rather notoriously, even after it has passed through the cat. It's much higher in protein than dog food needs to be. I agree that denying the dog access is likely to be the only solution.

Comment: A dog that is in the bedroom with you in his crate much less likely to bark. They are content that they are in the room with you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the cat food up on a counter where the cat can get to it but the dog can't.  If the cat does not get all of the medicine you can create worms in the cat that are immune to drug you are using to treat cat.

> That which does not kill a parasite makes it stronger

Answer (score 4):

Your dog can get a bit overweight from too many proteins from cat food. Cat food can also spoil dogs, especially puppies, because it tastes better than dog food. Theoretically your puppy's potential worms can also become resistant to the cats' dewormers and cause minor problems in the future - so make sure your puppy gets proper deworming as well.

Apart from serving your cat from a height, you can also try different dewormers, like top spot dewormers that get absorbed through the skin (talk to your family veterinarian about options). Otherwise, feed your cat while going for a walk with the dog, or feed them in different locations at the same time. By feeding a small quantity of palatable food (like Fancy Feast) with the dewormer powder on, a hungry cat will be more inclined to eat it all at one go, whereafter you feed the rest of the food. Also, as a side note, I always warn clients that feeding a cat from a counter encourages them to jump on your dinner table while you're eating.

Comment: All dogs have sub clinical worm infections. That's why we recommend routine 4 monthly deworming. In theory you are very correct, but practically it takes a huge worm insult (for example a kenneling or breeding facility or herd of sheep kept in intensive conditions) for resistance to become a true problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am out off time at the moment to research or ask the question, but if we don't already have something on Pets.SE that addressess "All dogs have sub clinical worm infections" I would encourage you to post the question and answer it. If we don't already have something it is completely ok and encouraged to post the question and supply your own answer.  There are some limits on this for very new users, not sure if you will hit auto limiter or not.

Answer (score -1):

Put the cat food somewhere that isn't within reach of a puppy.  Usually a countertop, short table, or any other elevated space is sufficient.  Eating cat food can give dogs diarrhea too which you definitely do not want in your home.